# Weird behavior in Python in array initialization

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the following you see a snippet of my Python program that I wrote to send APDU commands to smart cards. I used PySCard library in this program.

First Program :

```
for LOAD_KEY in validLoadCommands:
    data,sw1,sw2 =connection.transmit(LOAD_KEY)
    temp = LOAD_KEY
    x= temp[3]
    for j in range(0,len(LOAD_KEY)):
        LOAD_KEY[j]=hex(LOAD_KEY[j])
    print '   >>>',' Load Command :',
    for j in range(0,len(LOAD_KEY)):
        LOAD_KEY[j]=str(LOAD_KEY[j])
        if len(LOAD_KEY[j])==3:
            LOAD_KEY[j]=LOAD_KEY[j][0:2]+'0'+LOAD_KEY[j][2]
        print LOAD_KEY[j],
    print
    for j in range(0,len(data)):
        data[j]=hex(data[j])
    print '   <<<',' Data :',
    for j in range(0,len(data)):
        data[j]=str(data[j])
        if len(data[j])==3:
            data[j]=data[j][0:2]+'0'+data[j][2]
        print data[j],
    print '--',hex(sw1),hex(sw2)

    if (temp[2] == 0x00 or temp[2] == 0x20):
        keyType = 0x60
    else:
        keyType = 0x61

    AUTH = [0xFF, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, blockNum, keyType,temp[3]]
    print 'AUTH Command: ', AUTH
    data,sw1,sw2 =connection.transmit(AUTH)
    print data, sw1, sw2
```

And its output :

```
Auth Command: [255, 134, 0, 0, 5, 1, 0, 4, 97, '0x0e']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Erb4h1m\Desktop\Faraadis Alborz Card Reader\CRT-603-CZ1_Read1Block.py", line 199, in <module>
    data,sw1,sw2 =connection.transmit(AUTH)
  File "D:\Software\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartcard\CardConnectionDecorator.py", line 82, in transmit
    return self.component.transmit(bytes, protocol)
  File "D:\Software\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartcard\CardConnection.py", line 140, in transmit
    data, sw1, sw2 = self.doTransmit(bytes, protocol)
  File "D:\Software\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartcard\pcsc\PCSCCardConnection.py", line 173, in doTransmit
    hresult, response = SCardTransmit(self.hcard, pcscprotocolheader, bytes)
  File "D:\Software\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartcard\scard\scard.py", line 1329, in SCardTransmit
    return _scard.SCardTransmit(*args)
TypeError: Expected a list of bytes.
```

And when I replace `temp[3]` with `x`:

```
for LOAD_KEY in validLoadCommands:
    data,sw1,sw2 =connection.transmit(LOAD_KEY)
    temp = LOAD_KEY
    x= temp[3]
    for j in range(0,len(LOAD_KEY)):
        LOAD_KEY[j]=hex(LOAD_KEY[j])
    print '   >>>',' Load Command :',
    for j in range(0,len(LOAD_KEY)):
        LOAD_KEY[j]=str(LOAD_KEY[j])
        if len(LOAD_KEY[j])==3:
            LOAD_KEY[j]=LOAD_KEY[j][0:2]+'0'+LOAD_KEY[j][2]
        print LOAD_KEY[j],
    print
    for j in range(0,len(data)):
        data[j]=hex(data[j])
    print '   <<<',' Data :',
    for j in range(0,len(data)):
        data[j]=str(data[j])
        if len(data[j])==3:
            data[j]=data[j][0:2]+'0'+data[j][2]
        print data[j],
    print '--',hex(sw1),hex(sw2)

    if (temp[2] == 0x00 or temp[2] == 0x20):
        keyType = 0x60
    else:
        keyType = 0x61

    AUTH = [0xFF, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, blockNum, keyType, x]
    print 'AUTH Command: ', AUTH
    data,sw1,sw2 =connection.transmit(AUTH)
    print data, sw1, sw2
```

Then the output is:

```
AUTH: [255, 134, 0, 0, 5, 1, 0, 4, 97, 14]
[] 144 0
```

As you see above, in the second case I DON'T receive any error, while there is no difference between first program and second program! I only replaced

```
    AUTH = [0xFF, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, blockNum, keyType,temp[3]]
```

with:

```
    AUTH = [0xFF, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, blockNum, keyType,x]
```

and `x` is initialized with `temp[3]` in the top of program. neither `x` nor `temp[3]` didn't changed between the line of initialization and the line of error.

What is going here?

Comment: Why are you converting your lists of ints into lists of strings? All it seems to be doing is causing you  a headache. For instance, you if statement will *always* fail as you testing for equality between a string and an int.

Comment: If you really want to create strings for printing then only convert them when you need to print them (and don't modify the list). `"0x{:0>2x}".format(10)` produces `"0x0a"`. The bit between the braces is the format specifier for your number. The colon denotes talking about how to format the argument. `0>2` align the number on the right, padding up to at least two characters (if needed) with zeros. The `x` means to format the number in hexadecimal.

Comment: @Dunes When I change `LOAD_KEY` in the program, does the value of `temp` change also?

Comment: Yes. Because `LOAD_KEY` and `temp` are the same list object in memory. Perhaps you want `temp` to be a **copy** of `LOAD_KEY`. Use `temp = list(LOAD_KEY)` or `temp = LOAD_KEY[:]` to create a copy.

Comment: @Dunes Your comments must written in gold! :) Those are really useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `temp` variable reference `LOAD_KEY` (Line 3: `temp = LOAD_KEY`)

When `x= temp[3]` get called, it's the value of `LOAD_KEY` at index 3 right after your `connection.transmit` that is set.

When you are sending `temp[3]` for your `AUTH`, `LOAD_KEY` have changed and so does `temp[3]`. So it's not anymore the same value as `x`.

```
connection.transmit => LOAD_KEY is set => temp => [3] => x
*** LOAD_KEY changes ***
x => old value of temp[3] aka LOAD_KEY[3]
temp[3] => whatever your code have put in it
```

Edit: short example

```
>>> LOAD_KEY = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
>>> temp = LOAD_KEY
>>> x = temp[3]
>>> LOAD_KEY[3] = 'new value'
>>>
>>> LOAD_KEY[3]
'new value'
>>> temp[3]
'new value'
>>> x
'four'
```

Comment: _Your `temp` variable reference `LOAD_KEY` (Line 3: `temp = LOAD_KEY`)_ So when I change `LOAD_KEY`, the value of temp also change?

Comment: In the line `x= temp[3]` the `x` variable reference `temp[3]`. So when I change `LOAD_KEY` the value of `temp` will change automatically, and when `temp` change, the value of `temp[3]` and `x` variable will change automatically, Am I right?

Comment: See my edit for a comprehensible (hopefully) example.

Answer (score 2):

In you first example, `temp[3]` is a string (`'0x0e'`).

In your second example, `x` is an integer (`14`).

This is because you're converting the integer values of the `LOAD_KEY` list to an hexadecimal string with the following line:

```
LOAD_KEY[j] = hex(LOAD_KEY[j])
```

In order to convert a string in hexadecimal representation to an integer, use the second argument of the built-in type [int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) to set the base to 16:

```
>>> int('0x0e', 16)
14
```

Comment: You are right too, probably a mistake at line 9 `LOAD_KEY[j]=str(LOAD_KEY[j])`

Comment: The conversion to a string is earlier than that -- `LOAD_KEY[j]=hex(LOAD_KEY[j])`. The conversions seem to be entirely redundant.